# Using Apache Commons Codec decodeBase64 from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, interop, hex, base64

I am trying to decode a base64 string in Clojure using the Apache Commons Codec library.

I am able to use these methods in the library:

```
(ns decode.core
  (:import (org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64 Hex))
  (:gen-class))

(.encode (Hex.) "s")
(.decode (Hex.) "0a")
(.decode (Base64.) "s")
```

But when I try to use [`decodeBase64`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29) like `(.decodeBase64 (Base64.) "s")` I get

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: decodeBase64 for class
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod
(Reflector.java:53)
```

What am I doing wrong? It seems like I should be able to call `decodeBase64` just like I can call `decode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[decodeBase64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29) is a static java method. Here is how you call it in Clojure:

```
 (import '[org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64 Hex])
 (Base64/decodeBase64 "s")
```